# Finding "python-config --ldflags" on windows

Tags: python, c++, windows, cmake, g++

**Background**
I switched from ubuntu to windows whilst working on a python program. So now i reinstalled theano and a g++ library.

And as i understand configuring the gcc.cxxflags in the theano config file to "the output of *python-config --ldflags*".
([Ref](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/theano-users/N1Atufu-LGc/j1Z6v47TmZ4J))
Should fix my g++.exe error Exception in python.

**Setup**
I use windows 10, eclipse mars, pydev to run a file that uses the theano package.(And therefore transforms python code on runtime to compilable g++ code?!)

**Question**
Where can i find the output of the  *--ldflags* in this environment? Since i am on windows unfortunately i can not simply run python-config.

Comment: Whomever may stumble upon this question, because one tries to intsall theano with scipy-neuralnetworks on a windows 64bit machine. I eventually bypassed my question by following this explanation:
[link](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html)
//also works with python3.4 if You edit the necessary lines, also runs with AMD-Cards, if You run theano on  Your CPU.